# Helm Upgrade with different SubChart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

We have a helm chart with a subchart dependency. Now, in the latest release it was decided to use a different subchart (same component) but from a different "vendor" (like Bitnami).

The problem is that when we run helm upgrade on a cluster, the installation succeeds but the old subchart components are not automatically removed and we have to "manually" run `kubectl delete`.

This creates a lot of Ops problem because it does not fit well with our GitOps approach.

There is a way to automatically remove all previous subchart component when doing an helm upgrade?

This seems a normal scenario especially today with a lot of charts hosted by different companies (like Bitnami, Quay ecc), without encountering lock-in.

Comment: What chart was used? Is it public or selfmade? What are new chart and subchart? What resources were created and now are not deleted?

Comment: We have a chart, that originally as subchart was using: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx   Now we change subchart to the Bitnami one: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Helm Conditions](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/dependencies/#conditions-and-tags) to easily specify which dependencies should be installed.

I've created an example to illustrate how it works.

I have two dependencies declared in the `Chart.yaml` and I've defined in the `values.yaml` file that only `redis` should be installed:

```
$ cat test-chart/Chart.yaml                                                                                                                    
...
dependencies:
- name: redis
  version: "15.x.x"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  condition: redis.enabled
- name: memcached
  version: "5.x.x"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  condition: memcached.enabled

$ cat test-chart/values.yaml
...
redis:
  enabled: true
memcached:
  enabled: false
```

Let's install this chart to make sure only `redis` is installed:

```
$ helm install chart-1 test-chart
NAME: chart-1
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Nov 10 11:18:44 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
chart-1-redis-master-0     1/1     Running   0          107s
chart-1-redis-replicas-0   1/1     Running   0          107s
chart-1-redis-replicas-1   1/1     Running   0          66s
chart-1-redis-replicas-2   1/1     Running   0          32s
```

As you can see from the above output, `memcached` wasn't installed as expected.

Now suppose we want to install `memcached` instead of `redis`. All we need to do is change `memcached.enabled` and `redis.enabled` in the `values.yaml` file and upgrade the release:

```
$ cat test-chart/values.yaml
...
redis:
  enabled: false
memcached:
  enabled: true

$ helm upgrade chart-1 test-chart
Release "chart-1" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: chart-1
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Nov 10 11:21:49 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 2
TEST SUITE: None

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
chart-1-memcached-86847c8c4f-nt5wv   1/1     Running   0          21s
```

Everything seems fine, `redis` was uninstalled and `memcached` was installed.

Comment: Hi, we actually found that our issues was that our helm was pushed on Helm Repository with the /charts folder, and it was containing both version of Nginx (bitnami and k8s.gcr.io)..Removed it and it started working